# How to implement Blur effect of Instagram in my App

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, image-processing, instagram

In my application it is required to use blur effect like instagram. I have gone through

[This](https://github.com/esilverberg/ios-image-filters)
[This](https://github.com/tomsoft1/StackBluriOS)
and [This](http://incubator.quasimondo.com/processing/fast_blur_deluxe.php)

with the help of second link I can blur a image completely, but I have to apply blur effect on some fragments of images please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for either a tilt-shift effect or a selective blur.

I have GPU-accelerated implementations of both of these in my open source [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) framework.

See the [GPUImageTiltShiftFilter](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/blob/master/framework/Source/GPUImageTiltShiftFilter.m) and [GPUImageGaussianSelectiveBlurFilter](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/blob/master/framework/Source/GPUImageGaussianSelectiveBlurFilter.m) for these effects.